# Cannot find taglibrary descriptor for http://www.springframework.org/tags/form with Spring boot

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-form

I have a spring boot web project setup with following pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.crif</groupId>
<artifactId>sniperengine</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>sniperengine</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.minidev/json-smart -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.8</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0.pr1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        <!-- <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId> <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId> 
            </exclusion> </exclusions> -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- DBCP dependency -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Oracle JDBC driver -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.oracle</groupId> <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId> 
        <version>12.1.0</version> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>12.1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>SniperMail</groupId>
        <artifactId>SniperMail</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\SniperMail.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>SniperDomain</groupId>
        <artifactId>SniperDomain</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\SniperDomain.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>poi-3.9</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-3.9</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\poi-3.9.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang3-3.3.2</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3-3.3.2</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xbean-2.3.0</groupId>
        <artifactId>xbean-2.3.0</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\xbean-2.3.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xmlbeans-xmlpublic-2.4.0</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans-xmlpublic-2.4.0</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\xmlbeans-xmlpublic-2.4.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>poi-ooxml-3.9</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-3.9</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\poi-ooxml-3.9.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ReportBuilder</groupId>
        <artifactId>ReportBuilder</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\ReportBuilder.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity-dep</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>SniperGraph</groupId>
        <artifactId>SniperGraph</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\SniperGraph.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>SniperGraphDataMapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>SniperGraphDataMapper</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\SniperGraphDataMapper.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>BureauConnector</groupId>
        <artifactId>BureauConnector</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\BureauConnector.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>SniperScore</groupId>
        <artifactId>SniperScore</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\SniperScore.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>SniperFraudRuleEvaluator</groupId>
        <artifactId>SniperFraudRuleEvaluator</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\SniperFraudRuleEvaluator.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>inquiry-commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>inquiry-commons</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\inquiry-commons.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ccavutil</groupId>
        <artifactId>ccavutil</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\ccavutil.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xstream-1.4.2</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream-1.4.2</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\xstream-1.4.2.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>match-commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>match-commons</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\match-commons.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>SniperValidator</groupId>
        <artifactId>SniperValidator</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\SniperValidator.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>SniperMatch</groupId>
        <artifactId>SniperMatch</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\SniperMatch.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>Match</groupId>
        <artifactId>Match</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\match.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>SniperRule</groupId>
        <artifactId>SniperRule</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\SniperRule.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>VerificationConnector</groupId>
        <artifactId>VerificationConnector</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\VerificationConnector.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.crif.sniper</groupId>
        <artifactId>SniperCache</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\SniperCache.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\httpclient-4.3.2.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcore</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\httpcore-4.3.1.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>SniperES</groupId>
        <artifactId>SniperES</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\libs\SniperES.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have added the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency as suggested in documentation.

The project uses JSP for view layer and within the jsp I am trying to import Spring Form tag library. But I am not able to do it as it is showing  following error in JSP file:
`Cannot find tag library descriptor for "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"` when I try to import it in my jsp.

I am using following code to import the library in JSP file
`<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>`

Answer (score 1):

Add those dependency too.The `standard.jar` (taglib) library is used to enable the `JSTL` expression language in JSP page, and it’s always used together with the `jstl.jar`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: A Maven update of the project solved the problem. Thanks anyways for the answer. :)

Comment: If the answer is correct then accept and upvote the answer for fellow users of stackoverflow.